# PHP Authenticate in Sharepoint with CURL

Tags: php, authentication, sharepoint, curl, upload

I need your help with SharePoint authentication with PHP REST and CURL.
I would also like to ask for some more information on how to upload files to SharePoint server, using PHP and CURL.

I have read a lot of information on this topic so far, but I still have many questions.
And one more thing - are there any differences between the different versions of SharePoint (2007, 2010, 2013)

Comment: Your question(s) seems way to broad. Consider rewriting your problem statement with more concrete examples of what you need help with. Preferably with code.

Answer (score 0):

For the past year I've been developing a PHP library for the SharePoint REST API (2013).

To answer your question, have a look at the `create()` [method](https://github.com/wearearchitect/sharepoint-oauth-app-client/blob/master/docs/SPFile.md#create) on the [SPFile documentation](https://github.com/wearearchitect/sharepoint-oauth-app-client/blob/master/docs/SPFile.md).